# Does your data size reduces after upgrading DataStax Enterprise?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

We have upgraded from dse4.5 to dse4.8 . After running upgrade sstables on 4 nodes of my 10 node cluster , i see the size of my cluster shown in opscenter is reduced to 2.5TB from 3.2TB . However , there is no impact of it in production.
Does the data really get compressed or reduce in size after upgrading sstables ?

Comment: Did you have any snapshots previously and if so perhaps you run some cleanup on those?

Comment: We do have snapshots (old and new )lying on the nodes and haven't cleaned them up since long . But the OpsCenter shows the size of our data in /data directories .

Comment: How can the data size reduce after running upgradesstables

Comment: Compaction might play a part here you may have had pending compactions prior to the upgrade which have now completed. Snapshots will be under the data directory too, upgrade sstables will upgrade those too iirc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Answer posted by markc in the comment :*
Compaction might play a part here you may have had pending compactions prior to the upgrade which have now completed. Snapshots will be under the data directory too, upgrade sstables will upgrade those too iirc. – markc Feb 23 at 12:19